# Uber SDK (0.5.4) Booking Error - Requires at least one scope. Available scopes , code:unauthorized

Tags: android, uber-api

**Uber SDK 0.5.4** Booking Error

The following code is returning errors:

```
configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setClientId(HostUrl.LIVE_CLIENT_ID)
            .setRedirectUri(HostUrl.Redirect_Uri)
            .setServerToken(HostUrl.Uber_server_token)
            .setClientSecret("xxxxx")
            .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.PRODUCTION)
            .setEndpointRegion(SessionConfiguration.EndpointRegion.WORLD)
            .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.PLACES))
            .build();
```

---

```
UberSdk.initialize(configuration);

    accessTokenManager = new AccessTokenManager(LoginNetworks.this);
    mUberLoginManager = new LoginManager(accessTokenManager,
            new SampleLoginCallback(),
            configuration,
            CUSTOM_BUTTON_REQUEST_CODE);
```

---

```
mUberLoginManager.loginForImplicitGrant(LoginNetworks.this);
```

**Error**

{ message :Requires at least one scope. Available scopes , code:unauthorized }

when changing the scope as below:

```
.setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.REQUEST))
```

**Error**

login Error (UNKNOWN).

Any Help ! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you requested access to the request scope from the developer dashboard? Are you using your developer account to test?

Comment: Hi @dustin-whittle, Thanks for your note. We are using developer account to test. We have full access to request and request_receipt in the Uber Developer Dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are logging in using Implicit Grant, which does not support the `REQUEST` scope. `REQUEST` is a privileged scope (see more info [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/guides/scopes)) so you will need to use either Authorization Code Grant or Single Sign On for logging in.

Comment: Hi @john-brophy, thanks for your comments. Will check the configuration and post back on the results. Good day to you.

Comment: We redirect to uber app using Single sign-on using this:  mUberLoginManager.login(context);  
But we want to logged in using Webview within our App.  So if we use   
    mUberLoginManager.loginForAuthorizationCode(context);  

We get the AuthorizationCode, but we need AccessToken for Booking then how could we get the required AccessToken using this:

Comment: So if you use the Authorization Code grant, then you need to get the access token from your backend. The client log in will provide an authorization code to your server, and then your server exchanges that with the Uber oauth server to get an access token. You can then provide that access token to your client.